# Enable/Disable a Prestashop 8 module via Php is not reflected in the administration

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, php-8, prestashop-modules

I'm developing a PHP code that must activate or deactivate a Prestashop 8 module depending on a call. I am using the enable and disable methods of the modules, which correctly modify the "activate" value in the ps_module table. However, when I go to the Prestashop administration, the button displayed to enable or disable the module does not match the value in the database. Indeed, the button only changes if I click directly on "Activate" or "Deactivate" in the administration.

So I'm looking for a solution to understand why calling the enable and disable methods of Prestashop in PHP doesn't give the same behavior as when we go through the administration directly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*PS : Clear my cache does not solve my problem*

**POST request :**

```json
{
    "module_name": "demo_grid",
    "type": "enable"
}
```

**CODE :**

```php
$webhookData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$type = $webhookData['type'];
$module_name = $webhookData['module_name'];

switch($type) {
    case 'disable':
        Module::getInstanceByName($module_name)->disable();
        break;
    case 'enable':
        Module::getInstanceByName($module_name)->enable();
        break;
}
```

***Example with this module which is activated in bdd and not in admin :***

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help !

**--- UPDATE ---**

After some tests I realize that it is the folder var\cache\prod\doctrine which keeps cache and that I must remove so that the modifications are taken into account. I made this code but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to delete the doctrine cache via php

```php
...
   ...
   case 'enable':
      clearCacheDoctrine();
      ...
      break;
   ...
...

public function clearCacheDoctrine()
{
    $cacheDir = __DIR__ . '\\..\\..\\..\\var\\cache\\prod\\doctrine\\';
    self::deleteDir($cacheDir);
}

public static function deleteDir($dirPath) {
    if (! is_dir($dirPath)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("$dirPath must be a directory");
    }
    if (substr($dirPath, strlen($dirPath) - 1, 1) != '/') {
        $dirPath .= '/';
    }
    $files = glob($dirPath . '*', GLOB_MARK);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            self::deleteDir($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
    rmdir($dirPath);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks good - Make sure to check if enable() and disable() methods also add / remove the proper entry in ps_module_shop table

Comment: I have the modification in the table. After some research I realize that it comes from the doctrine cache. Do you know how to delete the doctrine cache via php ?

Comment: You can use Tools::clearSf2Cache();

Comment: Hello! Would you kindly report this issue in our repository? https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues

There should be an event called to clear the system's cache after enabling/disabling the module. There's something wrong under the hood.